# mysql alternative for key value query with multiple self joins

Tags: mysql, sql, key-value

I have a table with numerical filters (age, weight, salary, etc).
Since I do not know the filters in advance I have to use key value pairs:

```
company
id, name
1, ACME

users
id, name, company_id
1, jon doe, 1

filters
id, user_id, filter, value
1, 1, 'age', 30
2, 1, 'weight', 82
3, 2, 'salary', 50000
```

My queries retrieve users that belong to a specific company and match any combination of one or many filter criteria: e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users, filters as age, filters as weight
WHERE age.user_id = users.id
AND weight.user_id = users.id
AND age.filter = 'age'
AND age.value = 30
AND weight.filter = 'weight'
AND weight.value = 100
AND users.company_id = 1
```

The table contains many million rows and I have tried all possible index combinations for the filter, value, user_id columns.
The queries take many seconds to minutes.

Is there a better solution for my usecase?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I went up one hierarchy in my table/query structure to make it clearer what I mean. Let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select f.user_id
from filters f
where (f.filter, f.value) in ( ('age', 20), ('weight', 100) )
group by f.user_id
having count(distinct f.filter) = 2;
```

Comment: Would that also work with greate/less than conditions?

Comment: @Chris . . . You can expand the `where` to be `and`s and `or`s for that.